# Predicting the evolution of a linear model depending on a parameter

Tags: regression, predictive-models

I have sets of data depending on a experimental parameter (wt%, in the legend) that can be fitted linearly.
I would like to get the line corresponding to another value of that parameter, for example 10.

[image: Plot of the fits]

I thought that maybe I could make a linear fit for both the slope and the intercept as
$$slope = a*wt + b$$
$$intercept = c*wt + d$$

but maybe there is an actual statistical method to do so.

**EDIT**:
I understood the sense of @Tim answer: making just one regression. But I think there are a few mistakes though, so probably the correct answer is:

$$\begin{align}
y &= intercept + slope \times x + \varepsilon \\
&= a \times wt + b + c \times wt \times x + d \times wt +\varepsilon \\
&= \beta_0 + \beta_1 \times wt + \beta_2 \times x +  \beta_3 \times wt \times x + \varepsilon 
\end{align}$$

with this additional regressor I get a great fit (R-sq = 0.995).
[image: Result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing is just a regular regression model with an interaction term

$$\begin{align}
y &= intercept + slope \times x + \varepsilon \\
&= (b+d) + a \times wt + c \times wt \times x + \varepsilon \\
&= \beta_0 + \beta_1 \times wt + \beta_2 \times wt \times x + \varepsilon 
\end{align}$$

You can't have $b$ and $d$ as two intercepts, they wouldn't be identifiable because are redundant.

As you noticed in the edit, you may add the $\beta_2 x$ term to the model. It might improve performance or interpretability.     The term would tell you how much influence $x$ has on $y$ regardless of the experimental condition $wt$. There may be scenarios though where the additional parameter may not be necessary or desirable.

Comment: I see. I think you made a few mistakes though. Idk what's the etiquette here, I put the answer I think is right in an edit, if you prefer to change yours just tell me.

Comment: @Gabraltur your model in the edit is just another possible one, probably the one that makes more sense. My answer related to re-writing the model in your initial question. Both models are possible, neither is “correct” or “wrong”.